# Uncurrying curried Function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I have a function, which takes two arguments and returns a single value.

For example

```swift
func sum(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
    return x + y
}
```

Next step is to use a `currying` to get a function which takes the only first argument and return a closure with an appropriate signature.
Also, I wrote a type alias to bring more clearness of the result type.

```swift
typealias EscapingClosure<A, B> = (A) -> B
func curry<A, B, C>(_ f: @escaping (A, B) -> C) -> EscapingClosure<A, (B) -> C> {
    return { (a: A) -> ((_ b: B) -> C) in
        return { (b: B) -> C in f(a, b) }
    }
}
```

But then I remembered about `uncurry` function which should return a default `sum` function signature if I'll apply it on the curryied result.
So I tried to implement a variation of `uncurry`, and what I'll get at the result:

```swift
func uncarry<A, B, C>(_ f: @escaping EscapingClosure<A, (B) -> C>) -> (A, B) -> C {
    return { (a: A, b: B) -> C in
        return f(a)(b)
    }
}
```

But here's a problem - I can't use this `uncurry` function with the result of currying on `sum` function, because `uncurry` requires only **@escaping** parameter where curryied function returns a non-escaping variation.

Here's a Swift compiler error:

```swift
Cannot convert value of type '((A) -> Void) -> ()' to expected argument type '(_) -> (_) -> _'
```

Does anyone know are there any ways to create `uncurry` function in Swift which would be applicable to the curryied function result.

Comment: [It works fine for me](https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/GrumpyLightcyanStructs)

Comment: @Alexander agreed. I made an error, tried to run `uncurry(curry(sum)(100))` instead of `uncurry(curry(sum))`, and here's a compiler warned me.

Comment: I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `uncurry` function can do just that, uncurry curried functions:

```
let currableSum = curry(sum)
let uncurriedSum = uncurry(currableSum)

let add100 = currableSum(100)
print(add100(23)) // => 123

print(uncurriedSum(2, 2)) // => 4
```

The issue is that you're mistaking uncurrying for unapplying. Once you've partially or fully applied a curried function (or any function, for that matter), there's no mechanism to go back, to get the original function that produced the result.

```
uncurry(add100) // ❌ can't "unapply" a partially applied function
```

Imagine if that were the case. Every integer, string, and other value would have to remember a history of what functions caused it. I can't think of a single use case for that. For one, it would require dynamic typing (or forced compile-time casting in a static language like Swift), because you can't predict the signature of an arbitrary function that produces a given result.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexander write above, I can easily use `uncurry` function for curried result of the `sum()`.

I just made an error when passed a result value of the curried function.